# Ant Migration Tool - Only show test names in log

Tags: ant, migration-tool

I'm setting up a CI/CD workflow for Salesforce using Jenkins and the Ant Migration Tool. I'd like to be able to quickly glance at the console output and/or log and see the names of tests that are running so I have some way to track progress.

Every option in `logType` is far too verbose for what I'm looking for - I'm not really concerned about allocation of memory, DB insertions, or any of the other stuff. Is there a way to configure my build.xml so that it's only displaying the names of tests that have run? Something like this:

```
[sf:deploy] Running MyTest1 <100%>
[sf:deploy] Running MyTest2 <100%>
[sf:deploy] Running MyTest3 <100%>
[sf:deploy] Running MyTest4 <100%>
[sf:deploy] Running MyTest5 <FAILED>
```